# Notepad++: is there any add-on or regex or macro to split long text to sentence boundary

Tags: notepad++, regex, macros

I am doing translation work that required me to break long pages or paragraphs at sentence boundary, that is full-stop (.) for English, and Poorn-Viraam (।) for Hindi.

It is called "align"ing or (probably) tokenizing.

For Notepad++ (w9-32 bit), is there any add-on or regex or macro to split long text to sentences. (in plain text txt files).,

In regex, I can't just find . and replace with .\r\n because . is also used as abbreviation indication, say, in i.e., e.g., pvt., ltd., inc., etc.. so it would replace there also, that is not desirable. Also, if several sentences are there wihtin parentheses () [] {}, then also, these should not be broken.

So, I guess a single regex command just woundn't do, or it will become too complex to take care of all the possibilities.

it has to be a set of regex executed one after another, or a macro,

or if someone has developed some add-on for that?

### Thanks.

Rawat

Comment: oops! w9-32 bit -> w8-32 bit. sorry.

Comment: You're trying to handle natural languages. Without semantic information how would you specify the end of a sentence? Without the semantic that you know that `i.e.` is a short hand, how would know it's not the end of sentence? You might be able to write a regex that ignores the signs if the word before it has a "common" (3?) character length for an abbreviation. That's not going to be perfect but could help you?

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting... This seems like a valid question to me...

Answer (score 1):

As Seth explained, to *realy* do this propperly, would require natural language parsing. For now, this is only available through specialized implementations like the [Stanford parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), but not as Notepad++ plugins. But, given a few basic assumptions, I think you could hack your way around it using simple regex expressions.

I would start by making the assumption that sentences you want to split end with a '.', then have a space, and then a capital letter. This won't be perfect, but avoids the parentheses and abbreviation issue *in most cases*.

So...

```
\. [A-Z]
```

And maybe, if sentences start with a number...

```
\. [A-Z\d]
```

Then, maybe to make it a bit more whitespace-proof and handle the parentheses even better:

```
\.[^)\]}]*?\s+[^)\]}]*?[A-Z\d]
```

- \s+ - to match one or more whitespace characters
- [^)]}]*? to make sure there is no closing bracket behind the ., or the whitespace

I guess you can play around with this some more depending on your use case...

**Edit:**
I was pondering a bit longer on this. I think you could also make the assumption that while a sentence can *start* with just one letter (like the word 'I' or 'A'), it is unlikely to *end* on a one-letter word (in english).

So you could use

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\.[^)\]}]*?\s+[^)\]}]*?[A-Z\d]
```

As an overall strategy, it just comes down to looking back, and forward, for stuff you do or do not expect to find at the end or start of a sentence.